# MaxScale JSON cache rules

Tags: mysql, json, caching, mariadb, maxscale

I would like to know how to correctly format JSON cache rules to MaxScale. I need to store multiple tables for multiple databases and multiple users, how to correctly format this?

Here, i can store one table on one database and use it for one user.

```
{
    "store": [
        {
            "attribute": "table",
            "op": "=",
            "value": "databse_alpha.xhtml_content"
        }
    ],
    "use": [
        {
            "attribute": "user",
            "op": "=",
            "value": "'user_databse_1'@'%'"
        }
    ]

}
```

I need to create rule to store multiple databases for multiple users like `table1` and `table2` being accessed by `user1`, `table3` and `table4` being accessed by `user2`...and son on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Maxscale 2.1 it is only possible to give a single pair of store/use values for the cache filter rules.

I took the liberty of [opening a feature request](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MXS-1401) for MaxScale on the MariaDB Jira as it appears this functionality was not yet requested.

Answer (score 0):

I think that as workaround you should be able to create two cache filters, with a different set of rules, and then in your service use

```
filters = cache1 | cache2
```

Note that picking out the table using exact match, as in your sample above, implies that the statement has to be parsed, which carries a significant performance cost. You'll get much better performance if no matching is needed or if it is performed using regular expressions.